# Refer to incremental variables in R for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I am working on a Shiny app that will have a dynamic number of inputs. I wish to run a for loop to place all of those inputs in a single data frame, which will be used later. Each input is named varname_i, where i is the index number of the input.

Here is a reprex:

```
# base values that are required
departure <- "TYS"
arrival <- "TPA"

# initial df
trip_df <- dplyr::tibble(dep = departure,
       arr = arrival)

#counter from Shiny app - this works
btn <- 2

#dynamic input fields
departure_1 <- "TPA"
arrival_1 <- "YYZ"

departure_2 <- "YYZ"
arrival_2 <- "PIE"

# for loop

for(i in btn){
  tmp <- dplyr::tibble(dep = departure_[i],
                arr = arrival_[i])
  
  trip_df <- trip_df %>%
    add_row(tmp)
  
}
```

The departure_[i] / arrival_[i] should loop through departure_1, arrival_1, departure_2, arrival_2 to build the df. I'm simply not sure how to properly include the name in the loop

Comment: Are `departure_1`, `departure_2`, etc. the ids of dynamically created inputs in the Shiny app?

Comment: Yes. So, the i in the loop, being a number, refers directly to the id after "_"

Comment: How are you creating the `departure_1` and `departure_2 ` variables in the first place? Because having variables with indexes in their names generally makes things much harder to work with in R. It's betters to have related data in lists. Like `departure = list("TPA","YYZ")` and then you can get values out with `departure[[i]]` very easily.

Comment: Each one is a separate input box in Shiny, so technically it is `input$departure_1`, `input$departure_2`, etc.

Comment: You could try input[[paste0("departure_", i]].

Comment: @AnthonySchmidt I created a demo that I think shows how you can do what you want, unfortunately it's on my laptop - I'll post it as an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a demo App that hopefully shows how what I suggested works.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

airports<-c("Albuquerque International Sunport","Fort Worth Alliance Airport","Rick Husband Amarillo International Airport",
            "Austin Bergstrom International Airport","Beale Air Force Base","Birmingham-Shuttlesworth International Airport",
            "Buffalo Niagara International Airport","City of Colorado Springs Municipal Airport",
            "Corpus Christi International Airport","Cannon Air Force Base","Dallas Love Field",
            "Denver International Airport","Dallas Fort Worth International Airport","DLF Airport",
            "Dyess Air Force Base","Edwards Air Force Base","Fort Smith Regional Airport",
            "Fort Worth Meacham International Airport","Holloman Air Force Base","William P Hobby Airport",
            "Huntsville International Carl T Jones Field","George Bush Intercontinental Houston Airport",
            "John F Kennedy International Airport","McCarran International Airport","Los Angeles International Airport",
            "Lubbock Preston Smith International Airport","La Guardia Airport",
            "Bill & Hillary Clinton National Airport/Adams Field","Montgomery Regional (Dannelly Field) Airport",
            "Mobile Regional Airport","Metropolitan Oakland International Airport","Ontario International Airport",
            "Randolph Air Force Base","Reno Tahoe International Airport","Greater Rochester International Airport",
            "San Diego International Airport","San Antonio International Airport","San Francisco International Airport",
            "Norman Y. Mineta San Jose International Airport","Sacramento International Airport",
            "John Wayne Airport-Orange County Airport","Sheppard Air Force Base-Wichita Falls Municipal Airport",
            "Travis Air Force Base","Syracuse Hancock International Airport","Vandenberg Air Force Base",
            "Fairbanks International Airport","Ted Stevens Anchorage International Airport")


# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  title = 'Journeys',
  fluidRow(
    actionButton(inputId="action", label="Action"))
  ,
  
  column(4,
      # create some select inputs
      lapply(1:5, function(i) {
        textInput(inputId=paste0('departure_', i), label=paste0("Departure",i), value=sample(airports,1))
        
      })
    ),
  column(4,
         lapply(1:5, function(i) {
           textInput(inputId=paste0('arrival_', i), label=paste0("Arrival",i), value=sample(airports,1))
         })
  ),
  
  column(4,
      tableOutput("a_out")
      
    )
  )


# Server

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$action, {

  
    journeys<-sapply(1:5, function(i){
      tibble(Departure=input[[paste0("departure_",i)]], Arrival=input[[paste0("arrival_",i)]])
    })
    print(class(journeys))
    
    trip_df<- as.data.frame(t(journeys))
    
    output$a_out<-renderTable(trip_df)
  })
}

# Run 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```